# how to prevent gspread_dataframe.get_as_dataframe from reading #N/A with error messages

Tags: pandas, gspread

I'm using `gspread_dataframe` to read data in a Google Sheet to a pandas DataFrame. The Google Sheet has a #N/A with an error message. When reading into a DataFrame it brings in the error message:
[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe

credentials = ...
gsheet_client = gspread.service_account_from_dict(client_secrets)

gsheet_connection = gsheet_client.open("gsheet_name")
worksheet = gsheet_connection.worksheet("tab_name")

df = get_as_dataframe(
    worksheet,
    evaluate_formulas=True,
    parse_dates=True,
    usecols=list(range(1,21)),
    skiprows=8,
    na_values=["#N/A"],
)
```

```
60     #N/A (Did not find value '45306' in MATCH eval...
61     #N/A (Did not find value '45313' in MATCH eval...
62     #N/A (Did not find value '45320' in MATCH eval...
63     #N/A (Did not find value '45327' in MATCH eval...
64     #N/A (Did not find value '45334' in MATCH eval...
                             ...                        
274                                                  NaN
275                                                  NaN
276                                                  NaN
277                                                  NaN
278                                                  NaN
Name: COL1, Length: 219, dtype: object
```

Similar situation with `#DIV/0!`:

```
60     #DIV/0! (Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be...
61     #DIV/0! (Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be...
62     #DIV/0! (Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be...
63     #DIV/0! (Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be...
64     #DIV/0! (Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be...
                             ...                        
274                                                  NaN
275                                              Directo
276                                                  NaN
277                                                  NaN
278                                                  NaN
Name: COL2, Length: 219, dtype: object
```

What is the best way to convert anything starting with #N/A or #DIV/0! to `NaN`? If we can do it in the `get_as_dataframe()` function that would be great e.g. via `na_values=lambda x: ...`?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `convert anything starting with #N/A or #DIV/0! to NaN`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike no problem, I mean a string that begins with the string "#N/A" or "#DIV/0!" e.g. `#N/A  xyz` starts with `#N/A`. Maybe docs can explain better: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation like `#N/A (Did not find value '45306' in MATCH eval...`. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate your situation and find a solution, I would like to post it as an answer.